# VBA Web query with login+password

Tags: vba, excel, authentication, excel-web-query

Morning guys,

Using already answered questions on here i am still unable to get any code to work for my particular site, unfortunately as it is an internal website i cannot share the actual site.

The site is a .jsp login page could this be causing the issue? The macro opens the login page in IE but doesn't enter any user data into the fields or submit currently.

I also get error message "the object invoked has disconnected from it's clients" once the macro is running.

Microsoft internet controls is active and
Forms 2.0 is active in references also

I am fairly new to VBA to if i am missing anything obvious please let me know, i have lowered security settings within IE also.

**EDIT** I am somewhat sure this is to do with my form ID's but i can't see where i went wrong?

```
Sub GetTable()


    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim ieTable As Object
    Dim clip As DataObject


    'create a new instance of ie
    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer


    'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
    ieApp.Visible = True


    'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
    ieApp.Navigate "http://dss-gp-mida-002/MidasDS/login.jsp
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document


    'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
    With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .Username.Value = "Carterr"
    .Password.Value = "password"
    .submit
    End With
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


    'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
    ieApp.Navigate "http://dss-gp-mida-002/MidasDS/homepage.jsp"
    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop


    'get the table based on the table’s id
    Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
    Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("sampletable")


    'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
    If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
    End If


    'close 'er up
    ieApp.Quit
    Set ieApp = Nothing


    End Sub
```

Page Source:

```
<input type="hidden" name="urlwanted" value=""><input type="hidden" name="sourcePageURL" value=""><input type="hidden" name="ssoiid" value="">
<div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Username</label><input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password</label><input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
</div>
<script>
                    $("#username").keyup(function(event) {
                        if (event.which == 13) {
                              $("#loginform").submit();
                         }
                    });
                    $("#password").keyup(function(event) {
                        if (event.which == 13) {
                              $("#loginform").submit();
                         }
                    });
                </script>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="btn-group-vertical-justified">
<button name="login" type="button" value="Log In" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.loginform.ssoiid.value=&quot;&quot;;document.loginform.submit()">Log In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on how ofte you would have to log in / run the macro you could as a first step check if you are logged in. If not manually do so, and then run the rest of the macro.

Comment: @Luuklag the system will always log me out and does not save user's logins, just the way the website was set up.

Comment: I once had something similar. I had the code open the website, the log in manually, and run the rest of the code. As long as the code was running it stayed logged in. Something like this could work if you only have to run your code ocasionally.

Comment: @Luuklag thats exactly what i want, all it does is pull a user list from the website for the purpose of running KPI reports

Answer (score 1):

I used the following in something similar:

```
Set ie = GetIE("www.url.com")
 If Not ie is Nothing Then

  ie.navigate (strtarget) 'strtarget is the target url
  Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    If ie.LocationURL = "www.url.com/loginpage" Then
     MsgBox "Login Please!!"
    Else 
     pageText = ie.document.body.innertext
    End if
  Else
   MsgBox "IE not found!!"
  End if
```

It will display a messagebox which asks you to sign in if you land on the loginpage. Then you manually log in and start the script again.